# RegularExpression permitir maior que 0,00

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, regex

Valor falso:

```
0,00 -- false
```

Valor verdadeiro:

```
0,01 -- true
0,10 -- true
1,00 -- true
10,00 -- true
100,00 - true
1.000,00 -- true
10.000,00 -- true
100.000,00 --true
1.000.000,00 -- true
10.000.000,00 -- true
100.000.000,00 -- true
1.000.000.000,00 -- true
```

Ou seja só pode ser maior que 0,00.

Segue o código:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?!0,00)\d+\,\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Inválido")]
```

O problema está 1.000,00

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta alterar o seu código:

***Troca:***

`^(?!0,00)\d+\,\d{0,2}$`

***Por:***

```
^(?!0,00)\s*(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})*|0)(?:,\d{1,2})?$
```

Segue regex online:

https://regex101.com/r/ALgFkf/1

Answer (score 1):

#### Solução

`^(?!^(0{1,3}\.?)+(,00)?$)(\d{1,3}\.?)+(,\d\d?)?`

Seja Funcionando no [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/RYZG04/1)

Comment: Eu particularmente não gostei da detecção do separador de milhar. Parece que ele pode detectar `10.0.0.125,98`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu não queria ser tão pragmatístico, mas é possível, se você quiser, posso ver para fazer.